# `<main>': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am currently self teaching Ruby and am practicing methods. So, I just don't seem to understand why my console continuously prints out a error message after the proper conditional is printed. Any explanation would be appreciated!

```
def test(tester)
    if tester
        puts "yes";
        
    else
        puts "error";
    end
end

#call function
test(:tester).("hello world");
```

Output:

```
yes
main.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Why am I getting this error??

Comment: correct syntax to test(:tester) or if you want to chain further use test(:tester)&.("hello world"), but this code does not seems to support chain of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.(bar)` is syntactic sugar for `foo.call(bar)`. So, `test(:tester).("hello world")` is syntactic sugar for `test(:tester).call("hello world")`.

However, `test` returns `nil`, so you are calling `nil.("hello world")` which is the same as `nil.call("hello world")`, and if you look at [the documentation of `NilClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html), you can easily see that it does not have a method named `call`. (`NilClass` inherits from [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html) which in turn inherits from [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html) and [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html), so theoretically, the method could be defined there, but as you can easily check yourself, it isn't.)

Since you are calling a method that does not exist, you get a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response!! This was truly helpful for understanding. Thank you, this makes sense.